# Install es40 emulator from source code on ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, make

I try to install es40 emulator on Ubuntu 14.04.3

1. I unpack zip package
2. Then excute "sed -i -e 's/\r$//' configure*" to clear my code for unknown character in my configure file and then excute ./configure
3. Run "make" command, but get this error:

> root@aaaa-PC:~/Desktop/es40_cvs_20080503_1030_src# make cd . &&
>
> aclocal-1.10  /bin/bash: aclocal-1.10: command not found make: ***
>
> [aclocal.m4] Error 127

i installed some package say there:
https://github.com/a2o/snoopy/issues/71#issuecomment-105600040

but i get some error after make like this:

> root@hamed-PC:~/Desktop/es40_cvs_20080503_1030_src# make cd . &&
>   /bin/bash /home/hamed/Desktop/es40_cvs_20080503_1030_src/missing --run
>   aclocal-1.10  main::scan_file() called too early to check prototype at
>   /usr/bin/aclocal-1.10 line 616. configure.ac:52: warning: macro
>   `AM_PATH_SDL' not found in library configure.ac:57: warning: macro`
>   AM_PATH_PCAP' not found in library configure.ac:62: warning: macro
>   `AM_PATH_X11' not found in library  cd . && /bin/bash
>   /home/hamed/Desktop/es40_cvs_20080503_1030_src/missing --run
>   automake-1.10 --gnu  cd . && /bin/bash
>   /home/hamed/Desktop/es40_cvs_20080503_1030_src/missing --run autoconf
>   configure.ac:55: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PATH_SDL
>         If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
>         See the Autoconf documentation. configure.ac:60: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PATH_PCAP configure.ac:65: error: possibly
>   undefined macro: AM_PATH_X11 make: *** [configure] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

I believe you still have some makefiles or other files with the wrong encoding.

Try using "unzip -a es40.zip" to let your unzip program handle CRLF conversion.  See if that helps.